# why do i need factor when using gl.polygonOffset?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I don't understand how `polygonOffset` works with WebGL. I often find myself experimenting with the `factor` and `units` arguments.

I think i've gotten more consistent results with:

```
gl_Position.z += someEpsilon;
```

I know that a derivative is mentioned in the documentation, and it does seem to behave differently depending on the angle of a triangle.

Why can't I just somehow increment the depth value by some number of units, a single unit being the smallest number the depth buffer can hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I just somehow increment the depth value by some number of units, a single unit being the smallest number the depth buffer can hold?

Well, you can. According to equation (3.8) of the [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification, section 3.5.2 "Depth Offset", page 59](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf#page=69), the applied polygon offset `o` is:

> `o = m ∗ factor + r ∗ units`

where

> The minimum resolvable difference `r` is an implementation-dependent constant. It is the smallest difference in window coordinate `z` values that is guaranteed
>   to remain distinct throughout polygon rasterization and in the depth buffer.

So if you want `o` to be constant, just set `factor` to zero, and use some appropriate value for `units`, i.e. 1.0.

Comment: But i'm under the impression if it failed with a factor, it's going to fail even more without it, seeing how they compound? When i experience z fighting, before offsetting, some of the pixels that i want to show do show, others don't. It feels like it should work with just units = 1, but i'm convinced that it doesn't.

Comment: Well, first of all it is not clear which if you need a positive or negative offset. Second, useing just `units=1` might be too low. Due to the numerical inacurracies during interpolation, you already do get z erros in the resolvable range. Third, you should make sure to disable the polygon offset again. If you unconditionally render everything with the same offset, you will not gain anything.